# Why has Unanswered link disappeared in my profile

Tags: discussion, support, bug, profile-page

Today morning when I saw my profile in SO I just noticed that **Unanswered** link has been disappeared! Why this has happened! I can see the same in my friend's desktop when logged in with his profile but not mine. I don't find what has just happened! Attached images to show what I am trying to say! I do not even find this in other profiles of SE like Meta StackExchange, Stackoverflow meta etc., below are 2 images of the same issue for different sites.

**Stackoverflow Image**

[image: Stackoverflow]

**Stackoverflow meta**

[image: meta]

Comment: hmmm that is very strange - it is showing up for me on both

Comment: @santiago Yea! that's why I clarified with one of my friend's profile too and he has got that! If it is a ban kind of thing then I want to know why?

Comment: Thank you @jonsca for pointing in right direction!! I am happy to be part of new Navigation..